# How to understand the `Net pruing` via complexity penalty

Tags: neural-network

In Chapter6.10.3 'Net pruning', page53 of **An introduction to neural networks __ Kevin Gurney**. It introduce the `complexity penalty` into the back-propagation training algorithm. The `complexity penalty` is like as follow:

$$ E_c=\sum_{i}w_i $$
$$ E = E_t + \lambda E_c $$

`Et` is error  used so far based on input-output differences.
Then performing gradient descent on this total risk E.

**My question** : After doing derivation. The `complexity penalty` will dissapear. How can it affect the training

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E_c should be the sum of the absolute value of each w (L1). or the squared sum(L2)